# Does not fire ul li click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, html-lists

The problem is that jQuery doesn't fire when `ul li` is clicked.
I need your help to understand what is the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id=ulSemtMahalle class=ulList>
    <li><div class=divIlceHeader>Çukurova</div>
        <ul class=ulListSemt>
            <li id='liSemt61' > <div class='divSemt' name='chkIlceler' >  <input type='checkbox' id='chkSemt61'  class='big-checkbox'>Mahfesığmaz  </div> 
                <ul id=ulListMahalle>
                    <li id='liMahalle161' > <div class='divMahalle' name='chkIlceler' >  <input type='checkbox' id='chkMahalle161'  class='big-checkbox'>Belediyeevleri Mah.  </div> </li>  
                    <li id='liMahalle162' > <div class='divMahalle' name='chkIlceler' >  <input type='checkbox' id='chkMahalle162'  class='big-checkbox'>Beyazevler Mah.  </div> </li>  
                    <li id='liMahalle163' > <div class='divMahalle' name='chkIlceler' >  <input type='checkbox' id='chkMahalle163'  class='big-checkbox'>Esentepe Mah.  </div> </li>  
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul#ulListMahalle').on('click', 'li', function () {
    console.log("li clicked");
});
```

Comment: Do you put the click event in `$(documet).ready()`?

Comment: This works for me. You would see the li clicked comment in the console window of the browser. Also, make sure jquery plugin is added above the code and the code is added inside document.ready() function

Comment: Yes, I put the click event into  $(documet).ready() scope. 
I filled ulListMahalle dynamically with getJSON function.
May It be reason not to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not correct:

```
 $('#ulListMahalle').on('click', 'li', function () {
    alert("li clicked");
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6mvjrbtz/

Comment: I also try like that but not fire.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with your HTML code you just added. It still works

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You would see the li clicked comment in the console window of the browser. Also, make sure jquery plugin is added above the code and the code is added inside document.ready() function